# (ACM) Certificate validation via DNS configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created an SSL certificate via ACM and I'm attempting to validate it via DNS configuration.

I've got the CNAME record for the DNS configuration, but I've run into something that I'm not sure about. My registar, namecheap, won't allow me to set a CNAME on a domain while still keeping the custom DNS nameservers on the domain.

Eg.

```
ns-1281.awsdns

ns-1702.awsdns-26.co.uk

ns-211.awsdns-42.com
```

In order for AWS to validate the domain, would the DNS nameservers not need to be set in addition to the CNAME?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are AWS nameservers; set your DNS in Route 53 Hosted Zones.

Comment: Sorry, need more detail. I know that they are aws namesevers. What woudl i set dns in route 53 to and where would i set it?

Comment: Ah, i think I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: Go to Route 53 in the AWS console, select Hosted Zones in the left hand menu, create a new Record Set, and create a CNAME record with the values indicated in ACM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nameservers you have listed are AWS nameservers, which means AWS is handling your DNS.

To manage your DNS head over to Route 53 in the AWS console, select Hosted Zones in the left hand menu, select the hosted zone for your domain, create a new Record Set, and create a CNAME record with the values indicated in ACM.

Comment: thanks!! 
Last question. The Record value that aws gave me ends in a period. As domains don't typically end in a period, should I remove this before adding it to the cname record?

Comment: No need to add it; AWS will add it for you.